# Position flex children

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to display my ul menu at the top right but nothing i do seems to work, also I would like to change the whitespace between my ul but when I add padding it only messes up my inline display... What am I doing wrong?

```css
#menu {
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:12%;
    position:absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

li {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

#menu ul {
    float:right;    <!-- ????-->
    margin-right:5%; <!-- ????-->
}

h1 {
    margin-left:5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <h1>My Headder</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href = "index.html">Hello</a></li>
        <li><a href = "index.html">home</a></li>
        <li><a href = "index.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `#menu {right: 0}`

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float` has no effect on `flex` children, you may use `margin` or `align-self: end;`. or `justify-content:space-between` on the `flex` parent

example with `margin-left:auto` ... to push to the right a flex child.

```css
#menu {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#menu ul {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

h1 {
  margin-left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <h1>My Headder</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Hello</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

ressource or usefull reminder https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Just add justify-content: space-between; to #menu like so:

```
#menu {
    ...
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

and to add space between the li elements just add padding like:

```
#menu ul li {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

also, fix the styles for #menu ul:

```
#menu ul {
    margin-right: 5%;
}
```

no need for float: right; for the ul